# What does PROJECTION stage mean in mongo explain result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2

I am running a explain command on a shard cluster in mongodb shell. From the output I see the first `stage` under `inputStage` is `PROJECTION`. I don't quite understand what this stage means. And I couldn't find it on mongodb web site. Is there a definition for this stage?

```
"winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                            "transformBy" : {
                                "body" : 1,
                                "headers.Date" : 1
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "OR",
                                        "inputStages" : [
                                            {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "filename" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "filename_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                    "filename" : [ ]
                                                },
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "filename" : [
                                                        "[\"1046\", \"1046\"]"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "headers.From" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "headers.From_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                    "headers.From" : [ ]
                                                },
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "headers.From" : [
                                                        "[\"xxx@gmail.comm\", \"xxx@gmail.com\"]"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
```

The query command I used is:

```
db.testmsg.find(
{
  $or: [ { "filename": "1046"}, {"headers.From":"xxx@gmail.com"}]
},{
  "body": 1, "headers.Date": 1
  }).explain();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you query you have `,{"body": 1, "headers.Date": 1}` what is called "projection" where you tell to the query, what keys you want to get (+ _id). If you don't need `_id` in your result (you project `_id:0`) and all other keys can be found from index, result can be returned from index and database engine don't need to go to the actual collection to get `_id`  (that's because _id is always returned, except it is projected out; if index don't have _id as one of the fields, value must be read from disk)